# Datatables and jquery range slider to filter data

Tags: jquery, slider, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables, and a jqueryui range slider.

Datatables has a range filter built in, but using input boxes to enter your ranges. I want use a slider instead. Please can someone help me to modify the code below, to use the slider.

the current code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
/* Custom filtering function which will filter data in column four between two values */
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
var iMin = document.getElementById('min').value * 1;
var iMax = document.getElementById('max').value * 1;
var iVersion = aData[3] == "-" ? 0 : aData[3]*1;
if ( iMin == "" && iMax == "" )
{
return true;
}
else if ( iMin == "" && iVersion <= iMax )
{
return true;
}
else if ( iMin <= iVersion && "" == iMax )
{
return true;
}
else if ( iMin <= iVersion && iVersion <= iMax )
{
return true;
}
return false;
}
);

$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Initialise datatables */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    /* Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs */
        $('#min').keyup( function() { oTable.fnDraw(); } );
        $('#max').keyup( function() { oTable.fnDraw(); } );

} );
        </script> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $slider = $("#slider");//Caching slider object
    $amount = $("#amount");//Caching amount object
    $slider.slider({
        range: true, // necessary for creating a range slider
        min: 0, // minimum range of slider
        max: 50, //maximimum range of slider
        values: [0, 50], //initial range of slider
        step: 0.2,
        slide: function(event, ui) { // This event is triggered on every mouse move during slide.
            $amount.html('$' + ui.values[0] + ' - $' + ui.values[1]);//set value of  amount span to current slider values
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){//This event is triggered when the user stops sliding.

        //alert($slider.slider("values", 0));


        }
    });
    $amount.html('$' + $slider.slider("values", 0) + ' - $' + $slider.slider("values", 1));
});
</script>
```

I wasn't able to display the code easily readable here so I have added it to jsfiddle as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/ny32j/

Thanks

Comment: What are the two values to use to filter?Actual value of the slider and initial value of the slider?Are you using client side filtering?

Comment: Hi, 
yes i'm using client side filtering, the sample code uses:

$('#min').keyup( function() { oTable.fnDraw(); } );
      $('#max').keyup( function() { oTable.fnDraw(); } ); 

which is two input boxes on the page but i want to use the values $slider.slider("values", 0) and $slider.slider("values", 1)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first thing your range filter must have the value of the slider as iMin e iMax so i think you should do  (make sure you filter data on the correct column: in this example aData[3] filters on the 4 column):

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
//min value
var iMin = $slider.slider("values", 0)
//max value
var iMax = $slider.slider("values", 1)
var iVersion = aData[3] == "-" ? 0 : aData[3]*1;
if ( iMin == "" && iMax == "" )
{
return true;
}
else if ( iMin == "" && iVersion <= iMax )
{
return true;
}
else if ( iMin <= iVersion && "" == iMax )
{
return true;
}
else if ( iMin <= iVersion && iVersion <= iMax )
{
return true;
}
return false;
}
);
```

them you must redraw the tablke when the slider stops:

```
    stop: function(event, ui){//This event is triggered when the user stops sliding.
             oTable.fnDraw();
    }
```

i didn't test it of course, let me know what you get

Comment: Thank you it worked!! I had to switch the code blocks around so that the slider had been declared and changed  oTable.fnDraw(); to $('#example').dataTable().fnDraw();

really appreciate your help, once again thanks!!